# Getting the outliers of both dates and values

Tags: javascript, datetime, coffeescript

This is working now, but it looks very inelegant. I'm sure there is a nicer way of doing this.

```
# Get the outliers of both the dates and values 
maxDate   = []
minDate   = []
maxVal    = []
minVal    = []
for k, v of series
  for d, i in v   
    series[k][i][1] = nearZero if d[1] is 0 
  series[k] = v = _.filter  v,    (d) -> not _.isNull d[1]      
  maxDate.push  _.max       v,    (d) -> d[0]
  minDate.push  _.min       v,    (d) -> d[0]
  maxVal .push  _.max       v,    (d) -> d[1]
  minVal .push  _.min       v,    (d) -> d[1]
maxDate   = _.max _.map maxDate,  (d) -> d[0]
minDate   = _.min _.map minDate,  (d) -> d[0]
maxVal    = _.max _.map maxVal,   (d) -> d[1]
minVal    = _.min _.map minVal,   (d) -> d[1]
```

Comment: It would be good for people to test if you could add  example values for `series` and `nearZero`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some notes:

- I know many programmers like it, but this kind of perfectly aligned code looks pretty weird to me. Maybe my problem is that it's usually a sign that there is a repeated pattern that could be abstracted but has been prettified instead.
- `maxDate = []`. Using imperative programming in JS/CS is very common, indeed, but I'd definitely take a functional approach when doing maths or logic (not that I know of any coding that does *not* deal with maths or logic ;-)).
- `(d) -> d[0]`: Note that you can de-structure arrays: `([x, y]) -> x`.
- `_.map maxDate, (d) -> d[0]`. In my opinion list-comprehensions are more declarative than maps that use lambdas: `(d[0] for d in maxDate)`.
- Don't reuse variables: Those 4 accumulators hold two completely different structures in the course of the computation, that's not a good practice. Not even in imperative programming.

As I said, I'd write it in functional style, inmutable variables all the way through. It's a pity that CS has no *real* list-comprehensions and the results of nested loops must be flattened, but we'll have to live with it (`_.flatten(xs, true)` comes in handy as a one-level flattener). It would look something like this (you say you really need the modified series, so I'll use `mash` from my [mixin](https://gist.github.com/1222480)):

```
nested_date_value_pairs =
  for key, pairs of series
    for [date, val] in pairs when val isnt null
      [date, if val is 0 then nearZero else val]
modified_series = _.mash(_.zip(_.keys(series), nested_date_value_pairs))      
dates_values = _.zip(_.flatten(nested_date_value_pairs, true)...)
[[minDate, maxDate], [minVal, maxVal]] = ([_.min(xs), _.max(xs)] for xs in dates_values)
```

Comment: The only problem I have with this is that `series` does not get altered in your version. Its an unfortunately needed side-effect.

Comment: @Fresheyeball: In-place updated aren't compulsory, you can always create a new object. Is a bit harder? yes, but the algorithm is saner. Updated.

Comment: Thank you @tokland. Your coffee knowledge is formidably idomatic!

Answer (score 2):

For the max/min part of the problem, a solution using list comprehensions might be:

```
foo1 = (fn, i) ->
  # apply fn to i'th term of nested pairs
  fn((fn(x[i] for x in v) for k, v of series))

[maxDate, minDate, maxVal, minVal] = 
   [foo1(_.max, 0), foo1(_.min, 0), foo1(_.max, 1), foo1(_.min, 1)]
```

or without underscore

```
foo2 = (fn, i) ->
  fn((fn((x[i] for x in v)...) for k, v of series)...)
console.log (foo2(fn, i) for fn in [Math.max, Math.min] for i in [0,1])
```

Another with chaining:

```
wseries = _(series)
foo4 = (i)->
  wseries.map((v)->_.map(v,i)).flatten().value()

[[maxDate, minDate], [maxVal, minVal]] = 
  (fn(foo4(i)) for fn in [_.max, _.min] for i in [0,1])
```

These were tested with:

```
series = {
  1: [[0, .5],[4, -.1]],
  2: [[1, .4]],
  3: [[2, .2],[0, 0],[3, .7]]
}
nearZero = 0.1
```

producing

```
[ [ 4, 0 ], [ 0.7, -0.1 ] ]
```

for the initial filtering task, this appeals to my sense of aesthetics:

```
bar = (x)->
  [x[0], (if x[1] is 0 then nearZero else x[1])]
for k, v of series
  v = (bar(x) for x in v when x[1]!=null)
  series[k] = v
```

though with large dimensions, and sparse changes I can imagine being more selective about changing v.